# Usage of (dative) ihrem instead of (genitive) ihrer

Tags: dative, genitive

I came across this sentence,

> "daß Er ewig der Erhalter der individuellen Lebewesen ist, sowohl in ihrem bedingten als auch in ihrem befreiten Zustand"

However I was amazed to know ihrem is a Dative form (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ihrem) , whereas the sentence is referring to "their confined and also their liberated situation" i.e. hinting at  the possession of a state of consciousness (either confined or liberated)

so assuming there should be a genitive ihrer. 
Kindly advise

Comment: _"Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod"_ as the (old) saying goes (or was it the other way round??).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is simple. It's the preposition **in**. This preposition either takes dative or accusative. Never genitive.

> Sie stieg in ihr Auto. *(direction)*
>
> Sie saß in ihrem Auto. *(place)*

Your example isn't different. *Der Zustand* is a place *die Lebewesen* are in. I could even make it accusative:

> …, daß er ewig der Erhalter der individuellen Lebewesen ist, die er sowohl in ihren bedingten als auch in ihren befreiten Zustand versetzt hat.

That's because the verb *versetzen* calls for a direction.

If you wanted to see a genitive, you had to skip this preposition *in*:

> …, daß er ewig der Erhalter der individuellen Lebewesen ist, ihres bedingten als auch ihres befreiten Zustands.

However, *der Zustand* is now a property of *die Lebewesen* rather than a location.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that *sie* (referring to *die individuellen Lebewesen*) possess the *Zustand*. This is why the possessive pronoun *ihr* is used instead for what would otherwise be referred to by the pronoun *sie*:

> ihr bedingter als auch ihr befreiter Zustand

Now that whole phrase has to be in dative, though, as dictated by the preposition *in*:

> ihrem bedingten als auch ihrem befreiten Zustand